# Initialize classes from POST JSON data

Tags: python, json, django, class, deserialization

I am writing a Django app, which will send some data from the site to a python script to process. I am planning on sending this data as a JSON string (this need not be the case). Some of the values sent over would ideally be class instances, however this is clearly not possible, and the class name plus any arguments needed to initialize the class must some how be serialized into a JSON value before then being deserialized by the python script. This could be achieved with the code below, but it has several problems:

**My attempt**

I have put all the data needed for each class, in a list and used that to initialize each class:

```
import json


class Class1():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
        self._others = args


class Bar():

    POTENTIAL_OBJECTS = {"RANGE": range,
                         "Class1": Class1}

    def __init__(self, json_string):
        python_dict = json.loads(json_string)
        for key, value in python_dict.items():
            if isinstance(value, list) and value[0] in Bar.POTENTIAL_OBJECTS:
                setattr(self, key, Bar.POTENTIAL_OBJECTS[value[0]](*value[1], **value[2]))
            else:
                setattr(self, key, value)

example = ('{ "key_1":"Some string", "key_2":["heres", "a", "list"],'
           '"key_3":["RANGE", [10], {}], "key_4":["Class1", ["stuff"], {"stuff2":"x"}] }')

a = Bar(example)
```

**The Problems with my approach**

Apart from generally being a bit messy and not particularly elegant, there are other problems. Some of the lists in the JSON object will be generated by the user, and this obviously presents problems if the user uses a key from `POTENTIAL_OBJECTS`. (In a non-simplified version, Bar will have lots of subclasses, each with a second `POTENTIAL_OBJECTS` so keeping track of all the potential values for front-end validation would be tricky).

**My Question**

It feels like this must be a reasonably common thing that is needed and there must be some standard patterns or ways of achieving this. Is there a common/better approach/method to achieve this?

**EDIT:** I have realised, one way round the problem is to make all the keys in `POTENTIAL_OBJECTS` start with an underscore, and then validate against any underscores in user-inputs at the front-end. It still seems like there must be a better way to de-serialize from JSON to more complex objects than strings/ints/bools/lists etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having one master method to turn any arbitrary JSON into an arbitrary hierarchy of Python objects, the typical pattern would be to create a Django model for each type of thing you are trying to model. Relationships between them would then be modeled via [relationship fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) (ForeignKey, ManyToMany, etc, as appropriate). For instance, you might create a class `Employee` that models an employee, and a class `Paycheck`. `Paycheck` could then have a `ForeignKey` field named `issued_to` that refers to an `Employee`.

Note also that any scheme similar to the one you describe (where user-created JSON is translated directly into arbitrary Python objects) would have security implications, potentially allowing users to execute arbitrary code in the context of the Django server, though if you were to attempt it, the whitelist approach have started here would be a decent place to start as a way to do it safely.

In short, you're reinventing most of what Django already does for you. The Django ORM features will help you to create models of the specific things you are interested in, validate the data, turn those data into Python objects safely, and even save instances of these models in the database for retrieval later.

That said, if you are to parse a JSON string directly into an object hierarchy, you would have to do a full traversal instead of just going over the top-level items. To do that, you should look into doing something like a [depth-first traversal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaBEKo5sM7w), creating new model instances at each new node in the hierarchy. If you want to validate these inputs server-side, you'd need to replicate this work in Javascript as well.